# Google Kickstart: Round C, 2020: Stable Wall - Backtracking Solution Error

Tags: java, data-structures, backtracking

Here's the question I'm referring to: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ff43/00000000003379bb.

> Problem
>
> Apollo is playing a game involving polyominos. A polyomino is a shape
>   made by joining together one or more squares edge to edge to form a
>   single connected shape. The game involves combining N polyominos into
>   a single rectangular shape without any holes. Each polyomino is
>   labeled with a unique character from A to Z.
>
> Apollo has finished the game and created a rectangular wall containing
>   R rows and C columns. He took a picture and sent it to his friend
>   Selene. Selene likes pictures of walls, but she likes them even more
>   if they are stable walls. A wall is stable if it can be created by
>   adding polyominos one at a time to the wall so that each polyomino is
>   always supported. A polyomino is supported if each of its squares is
>   either on the ground, or has another square below it.
>
> Apollo would like to check if his wall is stable and if it is, prove
>   that fact to Selene by telling her the order in which he added the
>   polyominos.

**The analysis of this questions suggests a method to use topological sorting. I tried to come up with another method of solving the question (albeit slower), that solves the sample test cases correctly, but gives wrong answer (WA) on the full test set. Can anyone please point out the error in the logic and if possible, suggest methods to correct the same?**

The solution uses backtracking. First, we list out the unique characters on the ground floor - since at least one of those must be filled in first before adding shapes at the top. Then, we iterate over those, and for each send recursive calls using the adjacent elements as the next list of options. If we match the matrix given, we print it out, otherwise we return.

Here's the code -

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class StableWall {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Taking input in required format
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
        for(int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            String[] text = br.readLine().trim().split(" ");
            int r = Integer.parseInt(text[0]);
            int c = Integer.parseInt(text[1]);
            char[][] mat = new char[r][c];
            for(int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
                String line = br.readLine();
                char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
                for(int k = 0; k < c; k++)
                    mat[j][k] = chars[k];
            }
            System.out.printf("Case #%d: ", i+1);
            solve(mat, r, c);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static void solve(char[][] mat, int r, int c) {
        //make empty 2D array to hold current state of matrix
        char[][] currState = new char[r][c];
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                currState[i][j] = '0';
            }
        }

        //used holds list of alphabets we have already used and must not repeat
        ArrayList<Character> used = new ArrayList<>();

        //options holds list of alphabets that may hold the next possible alphabet
        //on first iteration, it contains elements of the first row
        //on subsequent recursive calls, it holds adjacent elements
        ArrayList<Character> options = firstRowElements(mat, r, c);

        //start function
        boolean val = recurse(mat, r, c, currState, options, used, 0);

        //print -1 if stable wall not possible
        if(!val)
            System.out.printf("-1\n");
    }

    static boolean recurse(char[][] mat, int r, int c, char[][] currState, ArrayList<Character> options, ArrayList<Character> used, int count) {

        //if we reach intended matrix state, print elements in order and return true
        if(equals(currState, mat, r, c)) {
            int len = used.size();
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                System.out.printf("%c", used.get(i));
            return true;
        }

        //create copy of current state since it will be modified in recursive calls
        char[][] currStateCopy = new char[r][c];
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < c; j++)
                currStateCopy[i][j] = currState[i][j];
        }
        //create copy of used elements since it will be modified in recursive calls
        ArrayList<Character> usedCopy = new ArrayList<>(used);

        int len = options.size();
        //loop over all available options
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            //fill current state with option i
            fillBoard(currStateCopy, mat, options.get(i), r, c);
            //add option i to list of used alphabets
            usedCopy.add(options.get(i));

            //if current state is not stable, reset state and used lists, and move to next iteration
            if(isFail(currStateCopy, r, c)) {
                for(int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
                    for(int k = 0; k < c; k++)
                        currStateCopy[j][k] = currState[j][k];
                }
                usedCopy = new ArrayList<>(used);
                continue;
            }

            //find options for next alphabet, by finding adjacent elements
            ArrayList<Character> new_options = findAdj(currStateCopy, mat, options.get(i), usedCopy, r, c);

            //if future call is true, stop and return true
            if(recurse(mat, r, c, currStateCopy, new_options, usedCopy, count+1))
                return true;

            //reset state and used lists
            for(int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
                for(int k = 0; k < c; k++)
                    currStateCopy[j][k] = currState[j][k];
            }
            usedCopy = new ArrayList<>(used);
        }

        return false;
    }

    //return list of unique alphabets in ground floor
    static ArrayList<Character> firstRowElements(char[][] mat, int r, int c) {
        ArrayList<Character> options = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            if(!options.contains(mat[r-1][i]))
                options.add(mat[r-1][i]);
        }
        return options;
    }

    //return true if current state equals intended final matrix state
    static boolean equals(char[][] currState, char[][] mat, int r, int c) {
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                if(mat[i][j] != currState[i][j])
                    return false;
            }
         }
        return true;
    }

    //fill the current state with all occurences of particular alphabet
    static void fillBoard(char[][] currState, char[][] mat, char ch, int r, int c) {
        for(int i = r-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                if(mat[i][j] == ch)
                    currState[i][j] = ch;
            }
        }
    }

    //return true if current state is not stable
    static boolean isFail(char[][] currState, int r, int c) {
        for(int i = 0; i < r-1; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                if(currState[i][j] != '0' && currState[i+1][j] == '0')
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    //find options by checking adjacent elements to the given alphabet
    static ArrayList<Character> findAdj(char[][] currState, char[][] mat, char ch, ArrayList<Character> used, int r, int c) {
        ArrayList<Character> options = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                if(mat[i][j] == ch) {
                    if(j < c-1 && mat[i][j+1] != '0' && !used.contains(mat[i][j+1]) && !options.contains(mat[i][j+1]))
                        options.add(mat[i][j+1]);
                    if(i < r-1 && mat[i+1][j] != '0' && !used.contains(mat[i+1][j]) && !options.contains(mat[i+1][j]))
                        options.add(mat[i+1][j]);
                    if(j >= 1 && mat[i][j-1] != '0' && !used.contains(mat[i][j-1]) && !options.contains(mat[i][j-1]))
                        options.add(mat[i][j-1]);
                    if(i >= 1 && mat[i-1][j] != '0' && !used.contains(mat[i-1][j]) && !options.contains(mat[i-1][j]))
                        options.add(mat[i-1][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        return options;
    }

    //print for debugging
    static void printMatrix(char[][] mat, int r, int c) {
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%c", mat[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define ANY_CHAR '0'

struct PairOrder
{
    //second musi isc po first
    //jesli wykryjemy odwrotnie to fail
    char first;
    char second;
    //bool used;

    bool operator <(const PairOrder& b) const
    {
        if (first < b.first)
            return true;
        if (first > b.first)
            return false;
        return second < b.second;
    }
};


int sizeX, sizeY;
char** map;
vector<PairOrder> orders;
vector<char> solution;
set<char> lettersUsed;


bool letterWasUsed(char letter)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < solution.size(); ++j)
    {
        if (solution[j] == letter)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool canPass(char symbol, int exclude)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < orders.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (i != exclude && orders[i].second == symbol)
        {
            char newSymbol = orders[i].first;
            //jak znajde symbol po prawej to musze sprawdzic czy po ten symbol po lewej uzyty
            if (!(newSymbol == ANY_CHAR || lettersUsed.find(newSymbol) != lettersUsed.end()))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }           
    }
    return true;
}

void solve(char symbol)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < orders.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (orders[i].first == symbol)
        {
            char letter = orders[i].second;
            if (canPass(letter, i))
            {
                if (letter != ANY_CHAR)
                {
                    solution.push_back(letter);
                    lettersUsed.insert(letter);
                }

                //found = true;
                solve(orders[i].second);
            }
        }
    }
}

void scanMap()
{
    set<PairOrder> orderSet;
    for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; ++x)
        {
            if (y < sizeY - 1)
            {
                char c1 = map[y + 1][x];
                char c2 = map[y    ][x];
                if (c1 != c2)
                    orderSet.insert({ c1, c2 });
            }
            else
            {
                orderSet.insert({ ANY_CHAR, map[y][x] });
            }
        }
    }
    orders.clear();
    for (auto order : orderSet)
    {
        orders.push_back(order);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int testCasesCount;
    cin >> testCasesCount;
    for (int test = 1; test <= testCasesCount; ++test)
    {
        cin >> sizeY; //rows
        cin >> sizeX; //columns

        set<char> letterSet;
        map = new char*[sizeY];
        for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; ++y)
        {
            map[y] = new char[sizeX];
            for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; ++x)
            {
                char c;
                cin >> c;
                map[y][x] = c;
                letterSet.insert(c);
            }
        }

        solution.clear();
        lettersUsed.clear();
        scanMap();
        solve(ANY_CHAR);

        cout << "Case #" << test << ": ";
        if (solution.size() == letterSet.size())
        {
            for (auto c : solution)
                cout << c;
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "-1" << endl;
        }
    }

    //system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I tested it on sample - works OK.
I tested it on many cases.

10
2 7
FBBDDCC
AAACCCE
3 3
DDD
BBC
AAA
3 3
AAA
AAA
AAA
3 3
ABC
DEF
GHI
3 3
AAC
BAA
AAA
3 5
DAAAC
DABAC
AABAC
3 3
AAA
ABA
ABA
3 3
ABA
ABA
AAA
1 1
A
5 1
A
B
C
D
A

It answers:
Case #1: ABFECD
Case #2: ABCD
Case #3: A
Case #4: GDAHEBIFC
Case #5: -1
Case #6: BADC
Case #7: BA
Case #8: AB
Case #9: A
Case #10: -1

So everything looks good.

But google always claims "Wrong Answer".

Can anyone can find a test that gives wrong answer to my solution?
Why Google claims Wrong Answer?

This is really anoying that someone write nice solution and have 0 points and even there is no way to get to know why...

Thanks for help.

Best Regards